# Scraping from a website based on a search

Tags: java, jsoup

#### Objective

In Java, I want to get the text output of the search result at [https://pin1yin1.com/#我是英国人](https://pin1yin1.com/#%E6%88%91%E6%98%AF%E8%8B%B1%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA) [image]

#### What I've tried so far

Using JSoup, I've connected to the page, using `Jsoup.connect("https://pin1yin1.com/#%E6%88%91%E6%98%AF%E8%8B%B1%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA").get();`

(the numbers and percents translate themselves into the Chinese characters)

#### Problem faced

When I run `getAllElements()` to see what it has scraped, the code is just for the landing page, i.e. what the user sees *before* doing the search, it doesn't pick up anything of the search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the website, you can get the data from their rest API directly, try below:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://pin1yin1.com/pinyin/convert/?c=%E6%88%91%E6%98%AF%E8%8B%B1%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA").get();
```

The response is below:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 { "q": "我是英国人", "s": "我是英国人", "t": "我是英國人", "p": 
["wo3","shi4","ying1","guo2","ren2"], "e": ["I; me; my","is; are; am; yes","British person"], "c": [1,1,3] }
 </body></html>
```

Comment: Just looking at the network calls on the website. If you found the answer useful please consider up voting and accepting. Thanks.

Comment: I have limited java experience. What are network calls and how does one find them?

Comment: Inspect the page, a section will open up on the browser, go to the network tab. There you'll see the calls website makes. It consists of API calls made to the backend to fetch the data, download js and html files or images etc. @ChrisA